# How to change the reporting services report service mode from Native to integrated?

Tags: sql-server, configuration, ssrs, ssrs-2016

In SSRS-2016, I am trying to change the Reporting  services report service mode from `Native` to `integrated`.

I added 2 new shared features to existing installation (See in the Pic)

[image: - List item]

I am trying to change the report server mode from native to integrated. I opened Reporting services configuration manager and add new report serve and add a database I am seeing just native mode option.

I am not seeing integrated option.

[image]

could you please suggest me on how I can make the report server mode to integrated?

I don't see that option. (I restarted after installing the 2 features)

Comment: You need to [reinstall to change the mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-sharepoint/reporting-services-report-server?view=sql-server-2016#overview-of-report-server-modes).

Comment: Thank you. I will try to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do this by creating a new ReportServer database and choosing integrated mode as mentioned [here](http://dereksan.blogspot.com/2011/01/how-to-switch-from-ssrs-native-mode-to.html) 
rather than going through a full re-install.

Comment: I tried to but I am not seeing the integrated mode option .